# Is there a difference between "torch.nn.CTCLoss" supported by PYTORCH and "CTCLoss" supported by torch_baidu_ctc?

Tags: python, pytorch, ctc

Is there a difference between "torch.nn.CTCLoss" supported by PYTORCH and "CTCLoss" supported by torch_baidu_ctc?

i think, I didn't notice any difference when I compared the tutorial code.

Does anyone know the true?

Tutorial code is located below.

```
import torch
from torch_baidu_ctc import ctc_loss, CTCLoss

# Activations. Shape T x N x D.
# T -> max number of frames/timesteps
# N -> minibatch size
# D -> number of output labels (including the CTC blank)
x = torch.rand(10, 3, 6)
# Target labels
y = torch.tensor([
# 1st sample
1, 1, 2, 5, 2,
# 2nd
1, 5, 2,
# 3rd
4, 4, 2, 3,
],
dtype=torch.int,
)
# Activations lengths
xs = torch.tensor([10, 6, 9], dtype=torch.int)
# Target lengths
ys = torch.tensor([5, 3, 4], dtype=torch.int)

# By default, the costs (negative log-likelihood) of all samples are 
summed.
# This is equivalent to:
#   ctc_loss(x, y, xs, ys, average_frames=False, reduction="sum")
loss1 = ctc_loss(x, y, xs, ys)

# You can also average the cost of each sample among the number of 
frames.
# The averaged costs are then summed.
loss2 = ctc_loss(x, y, xs, ys, average_frames=True)

# Instead of summing the costs of each sample, you can perform
# other `reductions`: "none", "sum", or "mean"
#
# Return an array with the loss of each individual sample
losses = ctc_loss(x, y, xs, ys, reduction="none")
#
# Compute the mean of the individual losses
loss3 = ctc_loss(x, y, xs, ys, reduction="mean")
#
# First, normalize loss by number of frames, later average losses
loss4 = ctc_loss(x, y, xs, ys, average_frames=True, reduction="mean")


# Finally, there's also a nn.Module to use this loss.
ctc = CTCLoss(average_frames=True, reduction="mean", blank=0)
loss4_2 = ctc(x, y, xs, ys)

# Note: the `blank` option is also available for `ctc_loss`.
# By default it is 0.
```

torch.nn.CTCLoss

```
T = 50      # Input sequence length
C = 20      # Number of classes (excluding blank)
N = 16      # Batch size
S = 30      # Target sequence length of longest target in batch
S_min = 10  # Minimum target length, for demonstration purposes

# Initialize random batch of input vectors, for *size = (T,N,C)
input = torch.randn(T, N, C).log_softmax(2).detach().requires_grad_()

# Initialize random batch of targets (0 = blank, 1:C+1 = classes)
target = torch.randint(low=1, high=C+1, size=(N, S), dtype=torch.long)

input_lengths = torch.full(size=(N,), fill_value=T, dtype=torch.long)
target_lengths = torch.randint(low=S_min, high=S, size=(N,), 
dtype=torch.long)
ctc_loss = nn.CTCLoss()
loss = ctc_loss(input, target, input_lengths, target_lengths)
loss.backward()
```

I am Korean. English is not my first language. So I'm not good at English. If there's anything that hasn't been delivered well, please leave a comment. I'll change the sentence as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

CTC loss only part of PyTorch since the [1.0 version](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v1.0.0) and it is a better way to go because it is natively part of PyTorch. If you are using PyTorch 1.0 or newer, use `torch.nn.CTCLoss`.

[warp-ctc](https://github.com/baidu-research/warp-ctc) does not seem to be maintained, the last commits changing the core code are from 2017. Later, they only fixed bindings for (an already obsolete version of) TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

Take care that Pytorch CTC loss takes log softmax probabilities as input while CTC loss by Baidu does not mention that.